# what's the behavior of this condition if(VALUE & 0xFF00)

Tags: c

what's the behavior the following condition :

```
 if (VALUE & 0xFF00) {
      // execute code
    }
```

should `VALUE` be equal to `0xFF00` or any positive result like `0xF000` led to execute the condition body?

Comment: The behaviour is: if it evaluates true, it is true, otherwise false (who upvotes questions which can be found by 10sec internet search?)..

Comment: For an expression `x` of integral type, `if (x)` is equivalent to `if (x != 0)`.

Comment: For "all of" flag checking, you may prefer `if ((x & set_of_flags) == set_of_flags)`.

Comment: Note that the paren in @KerrekSB 's comment is required because precedence of operator `&` operator is lower than operator `==`

Comment: @Olaf my sentiments exactly, but I am afraid we are just grumpy old geezers who are not having any fun.

Comment: @MikeNakis: Only speak for yourself; I do have quite some fun:-) But maybe, yes, I'm getting old. Thinking for oneself seems to become a diminishing virtue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the range of 16-bit integer values, any value between 0x0100 and 0xFFFF will lead to the body of the `if` being executed. Values between 0x0000 and 0x00FF do not have any of bits 8 to 15 set, so the condition evaluates to false and the block of code is not executed.

For larger numbers, any value `v` such that `v % 65536` has a remainder in the range 0x0100..0xFFFF will lead to the body of the `if` being executed.

Basically, if at least one of the bits in positions 8-15 is set, the code will be executed.

Note that the code is treated as if the condition was written:

```
if ((VALUE & 0xFF00) != 0)
```

Indeed, any expression `if (x)` is treated as if it were written `if ((x) != 0)` for any simple type of variable: integer, floating point, pointer.

Comment: how about value under 0x0100

Comment: Values between 0x0000 and 0x00FF do not have any of bits 8 to 15 set, so the condition evaluates to false and the block of code is not executed.

Comment: how about comment in the question  
`For an expression x of integral type, if (x) is equivalent to if (x != 0)`. he want to say that x has just not to be zero,

Answer (score 1):

The expression tests if one or more bit in bit 8 - bit 15 of `VALUE` is `1`.

If `VALUE` is one of `0x8000`, `0x4000`, `0x2000`, `0x1000`, `0x0800`, `0x0400`, `0x0200` or `0x0100`, the condition is true.

There are many other `VALUE`s to make the condition true, for example, `0x1234`, `0xC000`, `0xF000`, `0x0300`, `0xBEEF`, `0x0180` and `0xFFFF`.

If `VALUE` is `0x00FF`, the condition is false.

Comment: It will also be executed for 0x3A91.

Comment: @user2697817 Why the specific value?

Answer (score 1):

If any bit in `VALUE` that corresponds to a set bit in `0xFF00` is also set then the condition evaluates to `true`.

If you want to check that all corresponding bits of the left operand are set as in the right operand you should write

```
 if ( ( VALUE & 0xFF00 ) == 0xFF00 ) {
      // execute code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the expression `VALUE & 0xFF00` evaluates to non-zero, the if statement's body will execute.